# pycadf error while installing devstack kilo in ubuntu

Tags: openstack, devstack, keystone

- /usr/local/bin/keystone-manage db_sync
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/keystone-manage", line 4, in 
  **import**('pkg_resources').require('keystone==2015.1.3.dev15')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3138, in 
  @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3124, in _call_aside
  f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3151, in _initialize_master_working_set
  working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 663, in _build_master
  return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 676, in _build_from_requirements
  dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 849, in resolve
  raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pycadf<0.9.0,>=0.8.0' distribution was not found and is required by keystone
- exit_trap
- local r=1
  ++ jobs -p
- jobs=
- [[ -n '' ]]
- kill_spinner
- '[' '!' -z '' ']'
- [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
- echo 'Error on exit'
  Error on exit
- [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
- /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
  World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2016-01-08-084638.txt for details
- exit 1

Log file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/da3e29e34781fb2afc05

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue while running devstack. Looks like the pycadf lib is required for keystone.

I just had to install it: sudo pip install python-pycadf==0.6.0
and it worked for me.

Hope it works for you as well! Thanks.